# How does the MSMQ-Exchange Connector handle attachments?

Tags: msmq, attachment, exchange-server-2010

So here is my system: Users can email a document to a specified email address and that document will be automatically added into our system.  Currently this is process by a windows service that polls the Exchange server and processes messages whenever it finds them.

I'm attempting to move to a more distributed system where several services can process messages at the same time. To better serve this I'd like to use the MSMQ-Exchange Connector such that whenever emails arrive in the designated mailbox, they are automatically added to the MSMQ.

So how does the MSMQ-Exchange connector handle attachments? Most of the documentation I'm finding around the MSMQ-Exchange connector is for very old versions of MSMQ and Exchange.

Comment: Did you find a third party alternative or did you have to write one?

Comment: I ended up going with a polling method, I did not have the time to invest in a "better" solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't invest any time in the connector.

[Special Considerations for Server Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784508%28WS.10%29.aspx)

**Message Queuing**
Several features of previous versions of Microsoft® Message Queuing (MSMQ) have been removed from MSMQ version 3.0, which ships with Windows Server 2003.

Feature changes include:

- The MSMQ Exchange connector is no longer supported in Windows XP Professional and Windows Server 2003. It continues to be available for Windows NT Server 4.0 and Windows 2000.

Cheers
John Breakwell